# Area51's Share section is using Twitter's old logo, which Twitter's branding guidelines are against

Tags: feature-request, area-51, twitter, sharing

A variation of the old (*really* old) Twitter logo is being used in various places on Area51 when sharing is involved:

> [image: THE PROBLEM]

This goes against [Twitter's branding guidelines](https://about.twitter.com/company/brand-assets) (which have been in place for at least 4 years now), which state:

> **USAGE GUIDELINES** / IT’S A BIRD, NOT A PLANE
>
> The Twitter marks represent the core values of our brand, from meaningful connections in real time to simple amplified expression. Please don’t present the marks in a manner that suggests sponsorship or endorsement by Twitter, or confuse Twitter with another brand. Always use our official and unmodified Twitter logo to represent Twitter.
>
> [image: Twitter's Usage Guidelines]
>
> **Don't**
>
> - ...
> - Use older versions of the logo, previous logos, or any marks that may be confused with the brand